# How to get the name of a widget Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am working on a program where I create some widgets in a for loop. So I need to get the name of them dynamically. I have set up is when the mouse enters the frame. Which holds the two text label widgets. I causes a function to run. And I want to change the background color of a widget with the name of noteName. But I seem to have run into a stopping point and I can no figure it out. I have searched online but could not find much. SO does anyone here know how to get the name of a widget?

Code:

```
def get_children_hover(event):
        for widgets in event.widget.winfo_children():
            #This is here where I can not seem to figure out how to get the widgets name.
```

Can someone push me into the right direction.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the text of the label or do you want to see if `widgets` is a label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[winfo_children()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method) is the right thing to use but you are using it wrong. It is a method for parent widgets. (i.e. root, frame, canvas etc..)

Also:

> If the order doesn’t matter, you can get the same information from the
>   children widget attribute (it’s a dictionary mapping Tk widget names
>   to widget instances, so widget.children.values() gives you a list of
>   instances).

simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def foo():
    print ("Frame:", frm.winfo_children())
    print ("Root:", root.winfo_children())
    print ("children_values:", root.children.values())

root = tk.Tk()
frm = tk.Frame(root)
tk.Label(root,text="foo").pack()
btn = tk.Button(frm,text="FOOO",command=foo)
frm.pack()
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

about your code:

```
def get_children_hover(event):
    for widgets in root.winfo_children(): #assuming your Tk() instance named root
```